# Broken images on Github pages

Tags: html, css, github-pages

The images show up fine in local, but it doesn't show up in Github pages for some reason. I've tried checking for anything case sensitive but I can't find any differences (unless I completely missed it)

Here's the page https://jekkers08.github.io/Neils-Website/photos.html

and the repo https://github.com/Jekkers08/Neils-Website

None of the images on any html file shows up and I really can't tell why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jekyll will not copy files with a leading underscore. Therefore you need to rename your files to not contain leading underscores or disable Jekyll by adding a .nojekyll file in the root of your repository.

Comment: Thanks, adding the .nojekyll file did it